# Как загружать свой датасет для обучения через keras-tuner

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras

У меня есть код

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras_tuner import RandomSearch

training_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "DataSet",
    subset='training',
    validation_split=0.2,
    batch_size=8,
    seed=42,
    image_size=(640, 480),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    shuffle=True
)

def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    activation_choice = hp.Choice('activation', values=['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])
    model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('units_input',
                                   min_value=512,
                                   max_value=1024,
                                   step=32),
                    input_shape=(640, 480, 1),
                    activation=activation_choice))
    model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('units_hidden',
                                   min_value=128,
                                   max_value=600,
                                   step=32),
                    activation=activation_choice))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=hp.Choice('optimizer', values=['adam','rmsprop','SGD']),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model



tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5,
    directory='test_directory'
    )

tuner.search_space_summary()

tuner.search(training_dataset,
             epochs=5
             )
```

И у меня происходит такая ошибка

```
C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\python.exe H:\Python\Tensorflow\main.py 
Found 30002 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 24002 files for training.
2023-09-01 18:42:59.789244: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-09-01 18:43:00.154010: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5482 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Search space summary
Default search space size: 4
activation (Choice)
{'default': 'relu', 'conditions': [], 'values': ['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'], 'ordered': False}
units_input (Int)
{'default': None, 'conditions': [], 'min_value': 512, 'max_value': 1024, 'step': 32, 'sampling': 'linear'}
units_hidden (Int)
{'default': None, 'conditions': [], 'min_value': 128, 'max_value': 600, 'step': 32, 'sampling': 'linear'}
optimizer (Choice)
{'default': 'adam', 'conditions': [], 'values': ['adam', 'rmsprop', 'SGD'], 'ordered': False}

Search: Running Trial #3

Value             |Best Value So Far |Hyperparameter
tanh              |tanh              |activation
608               |1024              |units_input
192               |352               |units_hidden
rmsprop           |SGD               |optimizer

Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\base_tuner.py", line 270, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\base_tuner.py", line 235, in _run_and_update_trial
    results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\tuner.py", line 287, in run_trial
    obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\tuner.py", line 214, in _build_and_fit_model
    results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 144, in fit
    return model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\radce\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileu_pxyb0t.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1052, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 272, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1990, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5529, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 640, 480, 2) are incompatible

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python\Tensorflow\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    tuner.search(training_dataset,
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\base_tuner.py", line 231, in search
    self.on_trial_end(trial)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\base_tuner.py", line 335, in on_trial_end
    self.oracle.end_trial(trial)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\oracle.py", line 107, in wrapped_func
    ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\oracle.py", line 434, in end_trial
    self._check_consecutive_failures()
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\oracle.py", line 386, in _check_consecutive_failures
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures excceeded the limit of 3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\base_tuner.py", line 270, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\base_tuner.py", line 235, in _run_and_update_trial
    results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\tuner.py", line 287, in run_trial
    obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\tuner.py", line 214, in _build_and_fit_model
    results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 144, in fit
    return model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\radce\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileu_pxyb0t.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1052, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 272, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1990, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\radce\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5529, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 640, 480, 2) are incompatible
```

Она происходит из-за того, что размер ожидаемых и входных данных не совпадает.
Это происходит потому, что я для загрузки своего датасета использую `image_dataset_from_directory` есть ли способ загружать датасет так, что бы keras-tuner мог обучать на нём нейросеть?